# How to generate/create link automatically on every word of post in wordpress

Tags: posts, links, scripts

I am working on a poetry site and I am new to wordpress. I want to publish poems of various authors on my site. What i want is that when i publish a post, a link/onclick event on every word of post may be generated automatically in background. When a user click on any word of post, he may be directed to a new page containing poems with that similar word. Any help or direction will be appreciated a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the scale of your project, my solution will help you to get around it quickly, but it's inefficient when it comes to larger scaled projects.

**The easy way**

You can add a filter to `the_content` filter and finally link every word inside of the content to the search page of that specified word.

**The Hard Way**

This is way much better than the first solution when it comes to scale and efficiency.

By assuming that your content is in English and are divided using some character, the general process would be:

1. Adding a filter to the `wp_insert_post_data`.
2. Striping all link tags to prevent linking a word multiple times.
3. Using the `explode` function to get an array of words inside the poem.
4. Add links to the words by using a simple `foreach`.

To generate your link you can follow one of these approches:

1. Creating a custom post type and use a plugin like `posts2posts` to connect your posts and finally generating the link using `the_permalink` function.
2. Creating a custom table for keeping track of words and the connected posts.

   For the second approach, you have to add a query var by adding a filter to `query_vars` filter, create a custom shortcode to display your data and finally to generate the links you have to use `add_query_var` function and a hard-coded value of the page you're putting your shortcode.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I will definitely give it a try. Actually I am working on a poetry site in urdu language.